# SolidColorStroke error in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

My code was working fine while i was using Flex3, but since i switched to flex4, I get this error.

> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on mx.graphics::SolidColorStroke/apply(). Expected 3, got 1.
>       at CurrentTimeIndicator/updateDisplayList()[/usr/flex/elixir2.5/flex-suite/branches/release-2.5/build/bin/sources/library/calendar/src/flex/ilog/calendar/CurrentTimeIndicator.as:124]
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8876]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1010]
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/validateNow()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7953]
>       at flexlib.mdi.managers::MDIManager/executeDefaultBehavior()[C:\Users\Meg\Downloads\flexlib - 2.5 - flex4\src\flexlib\mdi\managers\MDIManager.as:506]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at flexlib.mdi.managers::MDIManager/windowEventProxy()[C:\Users\Meg\Downloads\flexlib - 2.5 - flex4\src\flexlib\mdi\managers\MDIManager.as:469]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12977]
>       at flexlib.mdi.managers::MDIManager/bringToFront()[C:\Users\Meg\Downloads\flexlib - 2.5 - flex4\src\flexlib\mdi\managers\MDIManager.as:946]
>       at flexlib.mdi.managers::MDIManager/add()[C:\Users\Meg\Downloads\flexlib - 2.5 - flex4\src\flexlib\mdi\managers\MDIManager.as:325]
>       at c7MenuBar$/show_calendar()[C:\development\flex_4_src\c7MenuBar.mxml:438]
>       at c7MenuBar/open_app()[C:\development\flex_4_src\c7MenuBar.mxml:235]
>       at c7MenuBar/__hList_itemClick()[C:\development\flex_4_src\c7MenuBar.mxml:566]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12977]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/mouseClickHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:10317]

I have figured its the ilog calendars mx:stroke thats giving me this error. If i comment it, I dont get the error:
The code looks like below, with mx:stroke commented:

> ```
>                      animationDuration="1000"              
>
>                      doubleClickEnabled="true"
>                      itemColorFunction="{itemColorFunction}"
>
>                      allowMultipleSelection="false"        
>
>                      startDisplayedTime="[8,0]"
>                      endDisplayedTime="[18,0]"
>                      showItemIndicators="true"
>                      columnHeaderEnabled="true" 
>                      startTimeField="startTime" 
>                      categoriesField="editable"            
>
>                      endTimeField="endTime"                
>
>                      summaryField="summary"
>                      calendarField="calendar">             
>
>
>           <!--ilog:currentTimeIndicatorStroke >
>             <mx:Stroke alpha="0.8" color="#9C35BE" weight="2" caps="none"
> ```
>
> />

Plz help.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stroke is deprecated since flex 4.Try using SolidColorStroke and see if the issue still happens.